# Adding ceiling fan wiring

Tags: wiring, switch, light

Currently I have one light switch that controls the outlet in the bedroom. I added a ceiling fan with light and ran 14/3 wire to the switch box. I will be adding another switch (dual function to control fan/light). How do I wire that additional switch to get power from existing switch that controls the outlet?
Diagram would be super helpful

Comment: Can you upload pictures of (a) the wires going to the original switch and (b) the wires going to the outlet? Do not disconnect any wires, just pull out the switch & outlet so we can see where all the wires go.

Comment: Yes, can you post photos looking into the back of the switch and outlet boxes please, without disconnecting the wiring of course?

Comment: "Diagram would be super helpful" yes, yes it would! Please [edit] one into your post of the existing wiring (and the pics, as requested above), and someone will be sure to be able to give you accurate advice. Unfortunately, there are too many options available based on the very limited info you've given us.